# Setting drive Allocation unit size in virtual envionrment

Tags: sql-server, configuration, virtualisation

Environment details:

- One physical host disk (RAID 10)
- Multiple virtual servers of varying types (app, web, SQL, file) all using same host disk
- using Hyper-V

Questions:

- Is it still beneficial to set an 'allocation unit size' of 64k on SQL VM's logical drives, if the physical host they use is set at 4k and cannot be changed?
- Could mis-alignment between virtual logical drives and physical disk actually
  cause performance degradation?

Comment: check out this link,scroll down all the way down to performance impact section:https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758814(v=sql.100).aspx